# How to position elements in the HTML using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Okay, this is a very beginner question. But I'm a beginner, so it's nice ¯_(ツ)_/¯

I started in CSS recently, and to save my acknowledge inside my brain, I search for some exercises.

And I see this base HTML:

And the following challenge:

[image: Create a CSS that allow doing this:]

So, I don't lose time and make my own version, there go ma code:

```css
.esqcima {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.esqbaixo {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 230px
}

.dircima {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 232px;
  left: 500px
}

.dirbaixo {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 500px
}
```

```html
<div class="esqcima">
  <p>Esquerda em Cima</p>
</div>

<div class="esqbaixo">
  <p>Esquerda em Baixo</p>
</div>

<div class="dircima">
  <p>Direita em Cima</p>
</div>

<div class="dirbaixo">
  <p>Direita em Baixo</p>
</div>
```

It works, but seems a little bit weird to me

You guys have a more simple way to do this?
Thx for the attention :)

Comment: You would do well to use [**HTML5 rather than HTML4**](https://html5boilerplate.com/)

Comment: What is actually wrong with the code you display? What is the issue? How have you tried to solve this issue?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question isn't clear or specific enough.

Comment: You can see that in the full screen demo your CSS doesn't work. You shouldn't be using specific left and top values, as they only work for one specific screen size. See absolute positioning and flexbox.

Comment: This is a `help me fix it` site, not `help me improve it` You bring broken code which you can't figure out, Not a working piece of code that you're trying to improve *(shouldn't worry about optimizing code while you're learning, that steps comes later)*, [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is much suited for such questions

Comment: All roads lead to Rome, just follow the one you feel ok with https://jsfiddle.net/s5v0y6qc/

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not professional too but I'll share my solution with you.

so first you better put all the squares in one parent div, for much reasons, for example you controle them better, I'll explain later

my HTML code

```
    <div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="esqcima">
        <p>Esquerda em Cima</p>
    </div>
      
    <div class="esqbaixo">
        <p>Esquerda em Baixo</p>
    </div>
      
    <div class="dircima">
        <p>Direita em Cima</p>
    </div>
      
    <div class="dirbaixo">
        <p>Direita em Baixo</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS code

```
*{
   margin: 0%;
   padding: 0%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parentDiv{
   width: 100%;
   height: 60vh;
   background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
   position: relative; 
}
.esqcima {
   background-color: red;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
 } 

.esqbaixo {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0%;
   top: 0%;
 }

.dircima {
   background-color: yellow;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0%;
}

.dirbaixo {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0%;
}
```

so when you put them on a parent div and this parent div have a postion relative, you can put the position absolute for child divs (I'm sorry for my english level) then you can control them by using the percentage, as you see the green square for example have in css `position: absolute;` and `right: 0%` that mean the square will be in the right, and like that on other squares

good luck

Answer (score 0):

positioning in CSS is actually very simple, there are multiple ways like
position: static;
for elements that will always stay in one position and aren't affected by anything
position: relative;
for elements that will be in their normal position till it's changed
position: fixed;
for elements that will stay the same even after you scroll
position: absolute;
for elements that will be positioned in relation to the nearest positioned element
text-align: (center, left, or right);
for text

NOTE: all can be modified with left, right, top, and bottom except static

Answer (score 0):

You could use a grid to do something similar.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-areas: "red  yellow" "green blue";
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.esqcima {
  background-color: red;
  grid-area: red;
}

.esqbaixo {
  background-color: green;
  grid-area: green;
  justify-self: start;
  align-self: end;
}

.dircima {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-area: yellow;
  justify-self: end;
}

.dirbaixo {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-area: blue;
  justify-self: end;
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="esqcima">
  <p>Esquerda em Cima</p>
</div>

<div class="esqbaixo">
  <p>Esquerda em Baixo</p>
</div>

<div class="dircima">
  <p>Direita em Cima</p>
</div>

<div class="dirbaixo">
  <p>Direita em Baixo</p>
</div>
```